# text search query building in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to build a stored procedure that takes input an array of varchars . It will search for these using syntax like

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE search_index @@ to_tsquery(' ');
```

If i give input to the procedure like tom ,dick,harry
the query should be dynamically build like

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE search_index @@ to_tsquery('tom | dick | harry ');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_search(search_terms character varying[], ent_id bigint)
  RETURNS entity_base AS

$BODY$DECLARE

  result_data entity_base;

  search_data text;
BEGIN

     search_data := array_to_string('search_terms[]', '|');

     SELECT * INTO result_data FROM entity_base WHERE search_index @@ to_tsquery(search_data) and entity_id = ent_id;
     RETURN result_data;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

When i run this im getting error

```
ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT  array_to_string('search_terms[]', '|')"
PL/pgSQL function "text_search" line 5 at assignment

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"
SQL state: 42804
Context: SQL statement "SELECT  array_to_string('search_terms[]', '|')"
PL/pgSQL function "text_search" line 5 at assignment
```

Comment: Use array_to_string(search_terms, '|'), without quotes because it's not a string, it's a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_to_string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-array.html)().